# please help in fixing this issue with simple javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, forms

```
while( $data is comming from db)
{
  <{form} name=formName.$uniqueValue action= onsubmit=return validate(this){>}

    <input type=text name=sort_order[] value= value_from_db />
    <input type='submit' />
  <{/form}>

}
```

Below is the Javascript validate function

```
{<}script language="javascript1.2"{>}
{function} validate(obj)
{

    var x = obj.elements['sort_order'].length;




    var check = false;

    for(var i =0; i <x; i++)
    {
        var array = Array();
        array = obj.elements['sort_order'];
        var num=  array[i];

        if(!isInteger(num.value))
        {
            check = true;
        }


    }

    if(check)
    {
        alert('Please enter a valid sort number');
        return false;
    }

    return true;


}

function isInteger(val)
{

    if(val==null)
    {

        return false;
    }
    if (val.length==0)
    {

        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) 
    {
        var ch = val.charAt(i)
        if (i == 0 && ch == "-")
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ch < "0" || ch > "9")
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

The problem is when i have values form with sort_order[] text field having more then 1 value the validation works fine but it fails when i have only one value in the sort_order[] 
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was when input field name is given an array i.e.  if the sort_order[] contains only one element then in the javascript it is not considered as an Array object . So that is why the value i was receiving was null i have put an check there if the value is null then consider it as an single element and then it worked fine. –

Answer (score 0):

keep the check value by default true and make it false if one validation also fails like this

```
var check = false;

for(var i =0; i <x; i++)
{
    var array = Array();
    array = obj.elements['sort_order'];
    var num=  array[i];

    if(!isInteger(num.value))
    {
        check = true;
    }


}
```

And for check Integer Value you can use `parseInt(val)`

Comment: The problem was when input field name is given an array i.e. <input type=text name=sort_order[] >  if the sort_order[] contains only one element then in the javascript it is not considered as an Array object . So that is why the value i was receiving was null i have put an check there if the value is null then consider it as an single element and then it worked fine.